# Directory.EnumerateFiles not retrieving the actual path

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Am trying to loop through a folder and read all the XML files within it.

Am using the `Directory.EnumerateFiles` to read from the path.

My .cs file and the XML files folder lies in same path

**"C:\User\Documents\Projects\TestTool"**

Am using the below code to get read the files.

```
string path = @"..\TestCases\";

foreach(string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml"))
{

}
```

Using this am getting exception stating

> Could not find path "C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\DevServer\TestCases"

This is pointing to the WebDev.WebServer20 path instead of the actual path.

Not sure why it is pointing to a completely different folder

I tried `string path = @"\TestCases\";` But when I try like this it is throwing an exceptiopn stating

> Could not find path "C:\TestCases"

What is the mistake am making? Please help

Comment: where is the compiled exe located when built? that is *usually* the default path when executing. It sounds like that is somewhere under `C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer`

Comment: as @MarcGravell said, or if you are using `httpcontext` you could use `context.Server.MapPath("~")` to get the "first half" of your file path.

Comment: This is a web application. Once i build I see the DLL is been generated in the path `C:\User\Documents\Projects\TestTool\bin`

Comment: it sounds to me like you have multiple projects in your solution, and one of them isn't where you think it is

Comment: @MarcGravell but if I specify the path as `string path = @"\TestCases\";` I do not see it going to the Program files folder

Comment: @Xavier why would it? the leading  \ takes it back to the root

Comment: You can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` to get to your executable file, though better use `MapPath` or similar if available.

Comment: @Evk yes... Am gonna try Server.MapPath() option

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
    string path = "..\\TestCases\\";

    foreach (FileInfo file in new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateFiles("*.xml"))
    {
        string filePath = file.FullName;
    }
```

Comment: No luck... Same exception again...
It is pointing to the same folder mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

Since it is running under WebDev server it will using WebDev.WebServer20.exe's path for all relative paths.

You must use: `Server.MapPath("~")` to get to your own root.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~") + @"\TestCases\";

foreach(string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml"))
{

}
```

Please note if `Server.MapPath("~")` points to bin, then use it like `Directory.GetParent(Server.MapPath("~")) + @"\TestCases\";`

Assuming this is your target directory `C:\User\Documents\Projects\TestTool\TestCases`